# Java generic method boundaries

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference in following 2 lines?

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int methodX(List<T> data)
public static <T> int methodX(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first option is a "stricter" parametrisation. Meaning, you're defining the class `T` with a bunch of restrictions, and then use it later on with `List`. In your second method, the parameter class `T` is generic with no conditions, and the `List`s class parameter is defined in terms of the parameter `T`.

The second way is syntactically different as well, with a `?` instead of the first option's `T`, because in the parameter definition you aren't defining the type parameter `T` but rather using it, so the second method cannot be as specific.

The practical difference that comes out of this is one of inheritance. Your first method needs to be a type that is comparable to a super class ***of itself***, whereas the second type need only be comparable to an unconditional/unrelated `T`:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Number> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Number o) {
        return 0;
    }
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int methodX(List<T> data) {
            return 0;
    }
    public static <T> int methodY(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> data) {
            return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        methodX(new ArrayList<Person>()); // stricter ==> compilation error
        methodY<Object>(new ArrayList<Person>());
    }
}
```

If you change the `Comparable` of `Person` to be able to compare `Object` or `Person` (the inheritance tree of the base class) then `methodX` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

To the callers, the 2nd version is roughly equivalent to

```
public static <T, X extends Comparable<? super T>> int methodX(List<X> data)
```

Suppose a caller calls it with an arg whose concrete type `List<Foo>`. Type inference will conclude that `X=Foo`. Then we get a new equation about T from `X`'s bound

```
=>
Foo   <:   Comparable<? super T>
```

( `A <: B` means A is a subtype of B)

If `Foo` is Comparable at all, it almost certainly `implements Comparable<Foo>` [2]

```
=>
Comparable<Foo>   <:   Comparable<? super T>
=>
T    <:    Foo
```

Without further information, inference chooses `T=Foo`.

Therefore from caller's POV, the two versions are not really different.

Inside method body, the 2nd version does not have access to type parameter `X`, which is a synthetic one introduced in compilation phase. This means you can only read from `data`. Things like

```
X x = data.get(0);
data.set(1, x);
```

are impossible in version#2; No such problem in version #1 with `T`.

However we can forward #2 to #1

```
<T1> method1(List<T1> data){ data.set(...); }

<T2> method2(List<?...> data)
{
    method1(data);
}
(they must have difference method names; overloading not allowed since java7)
```

This is because for the compiler, type of `data` is really `List<X>` (it knows the secrete `X`), so there is no problem calling `method1(data)` after inferring that `T1=X`

[1] JLS3, 5.1.10 Capture Conversion

[2] According to the javadoc of `Comparable`, *This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it.* That means if `Foo implements Comparable<W>`, W must be Foo or a super type of Foo. It is quite improbably for a subclass implementation to define a total order among objects of a super class. So `W` most definitely should be `Foo`. Otherwise funny things would happen. The notorious example is 'Timestamp', its javadoc (now) explains why it can't be compared with its supertype `Date`

Answer (score 0):

The first method expects a list of elements which can be compared against their *own class* or a supertype of it. Say, real numbers can be compared to any kind of numbers:

```
class Real extends Number implements Comparable<Number> {
    public int compareTo(Number o) ...
}
```

A bit more restrictive, but still acceptable for your first method is the following:

```
class Real extends Number implements Comparable<Real> {
    public int compareTo(Real o) ...
}
```

But the second method is actually not very different from this version:

```
public static int methodY(List<? extends Comparable<?>> data) ...
```

That is to say, you can replace `T` with an unnamed wildcard `?` because it is used only once in the method signature. It does not use concepts like *the same class* or an object's *own class*, etc.